# I can not remove a Registry key in code from Delphi

Tags: delphi, registry

Win7x64, DelphiXe.
Has written the program, which registers the control panel applet (as here recommend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757044.aspx).
All perfectly works, the applet is normally registered, displayed and started.

But at removal of a key of the register where it is registered:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\{0052D9FC-6764-4D29-A66F-2F3BD9E2BB40}

occurs nothing:

Create:

```
...
var reg1:tregistry;key:string;
begin
key:='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\ {0052D9FC-6764-4D29-A66F-2F3BD9E2BB40}';
reg1:=tregistry.Create;
reg1.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg1.Access: = KEY_WOW64_64KEY + KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
if reg1.Openkey(key,true)=true then showmessage('ok');
reg1.Closekey;
reg1.free;
end;
```

Delete:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click (Sender: TObject);
    var reg1:tregistry; key:string;
    begin
    reg1: = tregistry.Create;
    reg1.RootKey: = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    reg1.Access: = KEY_WOW64_64KEY + KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
    key: ='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace\{0052D9FC-6764-4D29-A66F-2F3BD9E2BB40}';
    if reg1.KeyExists (Key)=true then Showmesage ('Key exists'); // work
    if reg1.DeleteKey (Key)=true then Showmesage ('Ok'); // ! not work !
    Showmesage (inttostr(getlasterror)); // show "0"
    reg1.Free;
    end;
```

Errors any does not stand out, but the key does not leave. The program is started from under the accounting record of the admin (+ creates this key too it).
Through Regedit.exe a key it is visible and it is possible to remove.

What can stir to removal? :(

Comment: The TRegistry class simply wraps Windows API functions. Use the debugger and find out what the API functions return (especially RegDeleteKey). That will tell you why it fails.

Comment: Once again: the accounting record of the user - Local PC administrator, the rights to this branch of the register for this accounting record - are present. This key was created by this program started with these rights, and remove a key cannot.
Removal of keys in other branches of the register occurs normally. Through regedit.exe a key to remove it is possible.

Comment: (!) Aha, if to replace //showmessage (inttostr (getlasterror)); on showmessage (reg1.LastErrorMsg); shows "not found", both where it disappears and why then KeyExists fulfils norms?????

Comment: RegDeleteKey too does not work :(

Comment: Note - RegXXX functions doesnt SetLastError but rather return last error themselves.

Comment: It turns out the OP simply needs to separate the key that they open (which is like a folder) from the subkey they delete (like a file in a folder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF reg1.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel\NameSpace') THEN TRY
  reg1.DeleteKey('{0052D9FC-6764-4D29-A66F-2F3BD9E2BB40}')
FINALLY
  reg1.CloseKey
END;
```

Also make sure that there are no sub keys under this key. If there are, you'll need to explicitly delete these sub keys before you can delete the parent key.